# [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "37" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

```py
def resave_road_2(self, road_obj, new_hw):
    for new_obj in new_hw:
        if new_obj.data["road"] is not None:
            print(new_obj.data)
```

У меня есть эта функция где нужно показать только те объекты где  road не пустой. Однако мне программа  отправляет ошибку

> {'road': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "56" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}

По такому pk "56" в базе нет объекта
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: "как-то обойти эту проблему" использовать  исключения  try/except.

Comment: что передается в `new_hw`? Какие объекты. Это `QuerySet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй try - except. Дальше сам обработай исключение как тебе нужно

```py
def resave_road_2(self, road_obj, new_hw):
     try:
        for new_obj in new_hw:
            if new_obj.data["road"] is not None:
                print(new_obj.data)
     except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Ошибка: {ex}")
```